# How to force cast typed dicts to avoid Incompatible types in assignment

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I am trying to do the following (simplified example) in a high efficiency function (trying to avoid copy), without using `NotRequired` (for reasons shown after):

```
Mytd1 = TypedDict("Mytd1", {a: NotRequired[str], x: int})
Mytd_extra = TypedDict("Mytd_extra", {a: str, x: int, z: str})


def foo(y: Mytd1) -> Mytd_extra:
    # users input object should NOT contain z
    y = cast(Mytd_extra, y). # fails - my guess is `a` is the offender
    y["z"] = "hooray"
    if "a" not in y:
        y["a"] = "whatever"
    return y
```

Mypy complains about the cast as "incompatible types in assignment", but it's what I want to do. How do I achieve this? I think `a` is the offender - it's required on the output type

I do *not* want:

```
# kill Mytd1 
Mytd_extra = TypedDict("Mytd_extra", {x: int, z: NotRequired[str]})
```

because this would allow the client to pass in `{x: 5, z: "asdf"}` into `foo` but that should be forbidden - they are only allowed to pass `{x: 5}`.

I think the following would be doable but I'm trying to avoid it for efficiency as this function is called many times:

```
def foo(y: Mytd1) -> Mytd_extra:
    new_var: Mytd_extra = {k: v for k:v in y.items()}
    new_var["z"] = "ohno"
    return new_var
```

Comment: Mypy has an [`allow_redefinition`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-allow_redefinition) config parameter that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two completely valid solutions (assuming python 3.11 not to bother with `typing` vs `typing_extensions`, adjust your imports if needed). The problem is that `y` is of type `Mytd1`, so you cannot assign `Mytd_extra` (result of cast) to it.

### Use another variable

```py
from typing import TypedDict, NotRequired, cast

Mytd1 = TypedDict("Mytd1", {'a': NotRequired[str], 'x': int})
Mytd_extra = TypedDict("Mytd_extra", {'a': str, 'x': int, 'z': str})


def foo(orig_y: Mytd1) -> Mytd_extra:
    # users input object should NOT contain z
    y = cast(Mytd_extra, orig_y)
    y["z"] = "hooray"
    if "a" not in y:
        y["a"] = "whatever"
    return y
```

Here is [a playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=bd757d2242e1fd0b860c63929c20492a) with this solution.

### Allow redefinition (mypy flag)

Preserve your original code, but run with `--allow-redefinition`  (or add `allow_redefinition = true` to config file you use): [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=allow-redefinition&gist=70cddfd0ee4fc9d936db98ecacb585cf).

**Warning:** `allow_redefinition` does not have Super Cow Powers, it's use case is limited to a single scenario: assignment to a pre-defined variable, when expression in RHS includes this variable. It allows the following:

```py
y = 'abc'
y = list(y)
```

but not this:

```py
y = 'abc'
y = 1
```